# Javascript for loop return results to nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I am trying to return a selection of data from a nested array to a new nested array but the data is just being pushed into array.

```
var selection = [0,1,3,4];
var allProductData = [['Item1Sku','Item1Name', 'Item1Desc', 'Item1Price', 'Item1Available', 'Item1Margin'], ['Item2Sku','Item2Name', 'Item2Desc', 'Item2Price', 'Item2Available', 'Item2Margin'], ['Item3Sku','Item3Name', 'Item3Desc', 'Item3Price', 'Item3Available', 'Item3Margin']]
var selectedProductData = []

for(var apd=0; apd<allProductData.length; apd++) {
  for(var spd=0; spd<allProductData[apd].length; spd++) {
    for(var s=0; s<selection.length; s++) {
      if(allProductData[apd].indexOf(allProductData[apd][spd]) === selection[s]) {
        selectedProductData.push(allProductData[apd][spd])
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(selectedProductData)
```

This returns the following

```
[
  "Item1Sku","Item1Name","Item1Price","Item1Available",
  "Item2Sku","Item2Name","Item2Price","Item2Available",
  "Item3Sku","Item3Name","Item3Price","Item3Available"
]
```

What I want is

```
[
  ["Item1Sku","Item1Name","Item1Price","Item1Available"],
  ["Item2Sku","Item2Name","Item2Price","Item2Available"],
  ["Item3Sku","Item3Name","Item3Price","Item3Available"]
]
```

Any help with this would be great.

Comment: ... looking for an approach one encounters 2 times a 1:1 relationship for the given arrays, thus the, in my opinion, most elegant/readable solutions would be approaches that are solely based on [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: @PeterSeliger, complicated is better ... as the accepted answer. sigh.

Comment: @NinaScholz ... agreed, but the advantage of the accepted A is, that the OP clearly can retrace/reproduce/understand at which point at the code the conceptional thinking was not careful enough. And the additional answers give the OP something to think about and learn/grow from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create another array inside the first for loop and push the result in that array first, then push that array into the final array:

```js
var selection = [0,1,3,4];
var allProductData = [['Item1Sku','Item1Name', 'Item1Desc', 'Item1Price', 'Item1Available', 'Item1Margin'], ['Item2Sku','Item2Name', 'Item2Desc', 'Item2Price', 'Item2Available', 'Item2Margin'], ['Item3Sku','Item3Name', 'Item3Desc', 'Item3Price', 'Item3Available', 'Item3Margin']]
var selectedProductData = []

for(var apd=0; apd<allProductData.length; apd++) {
  var temp = []; // declare an array here
  for(var spd=0; spd<allProductData[apd].length; spd++) {
    for(var s=0; s<selection.length; s++) {
      if(allProductData[apd].indexOf(allProductData[apd][spd]) === selection[s]) {
        temp.push(allProductData[apd][spd]); // push the result 
      }
    }
  }
  selectedProductData.push(temp); // push the array into the final array
}
console.log(selectedProductData)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could map the data and the values at the wanted index.

```js
const
    selection = [0, 1, 3, 4],
    allProductData = [['Item1Sku', 'Item1Name', 'Item1Desc', 'Item1Price', 'Item1Available', 'Item1Margin'], ['Item2Sku', 'Item2Name', 'Item2Desc', 'Item2Price', 'Item2Available', 'Item2Margin'], ['Item3Sku', 'Item3Name', 'Item3Desc', 'Item3Price', 'Item3Available', 'Item3Margin']],
    selectedProductData = allProductData.map(values => selection.map(i => values[i]));

console.log(selectedProductData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to reduce the array and check if each current element's index lies within the selection array or not, if it does then push it.

```js
const selection = [0, 1, 3, 4];
const allProductData = [
  ['Item1Sku', 'Item1Name', 'Item1Desc', 'Item1Price', 'Item1Available', 'Item1Margin'],
  ['Item2Sku', 'Item2Name', 'Item2Desc', 'Item2Price', 'Item2Available', 'Item2Margin'],
  ['Item3Sku', 'Item3Name', 'Item3Desc', 'Item3Price', 'Item3Available', 'Item3Margin']
];

const selectedProductData = allProductData.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const filtered = curr.filter((product, idx) => selection.includes(idx));

  if (filtered.length) {
    acc.push(filtered);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(selectedProductData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `for...of` instead of `i=0;i<x;i++` it's more readable and can help you with the flow.

Also you can reach each element index inside your first loop, instead of setting `selection` array. you would still write it only one time and spare a loop.

```js
var allProductData = [['Item1Sku', 'Item1Name', 'Item1Desc', 'Item1Price', 'Item1Available', 'Item1Margin'],['Item2Sku', 'Item2Name', 'Item2Desc', 'Item2Price', 'Item2Available', 'Item2Margin'],['Item3Sku', 'Item3Name', 'Item3Desc', 'Item3Price', 'Item3Available', 'Item3Margin']];
var selectedProductData = [];

for (let data of allProductData) {
  selectedProductData.push([data[0], data[1], data[3], data[4]]);
}

console.log(selectedProductData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like the below snippet does the work you want.
Additionally see:

- [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
let selection = [0,1,3,4];
let allProductData = [['Item1Sku','Item1Name', 'Item1Desc', 'Item1Price', 'Item1Available', 'Item1Margin'], ['Item2Sku','Item2Name', 'Item2Desc', 'Item2Price', 'Item2Available', 'Item2Margin'], ['Item3Sku','Item3Name', 'Item3Desc', 'Item3Price', 'Item3Available', 'Item3Margin']];
let filtered = allProductData.map(item => item.filter((val,index) => selection.includes(index)));
console.log(filtered);
```

> There was a lot of noise about this syntax (snippet below).on comments, about the fact that the callback function in `filter()` having to evaluate to true. The actual words in **MDN** are:

> Function is a predicate, to test each element of the array. Return
> true to keep the element, false otherwise

```js
let selection = [0,1,3,4];
let allProductData = [['Item1Sku','Item1Name', 'Item1Desc', 'Item1Price', 'Item1Available', 'Item1Margin'], ['Item2Sku','Item2Name', 'Item2Desc', 'Item2Price', 'Item2Available', 'Item2Margin'], ['Item3Sku','Item3Name', 'Item3Desc', 'Item3Price', 'Item3Available', 'Item3Margin']];
let filtered = allProductData.map(item => 
  item.filter((val,index) => {
  if(selection.includes(index)) {
    return val;
  }
  })
);
console.log(filtered);
```

So here are some examples that do the exact same thing without raising an error. In all cases what is returned by `.filter()` is the logical true that will match the conditions in the callback function.

```js
let selection = [0,1,3,4];
let allProductData = [['Item1Sku','Item1Name', 'Item1Desc', 'Item1Price', 'Item1Available', 'Item1Margin'], ['Item2Sku','Item2Name', 'Item2Desc', 'Item2Price', 'Item2Available', 'Item2Margin'], ['Item3Sku','Item3Name', 'Item3Desc', 'Item3Price', 'Item3Available', 'Item3Margin']];
let filtered = allProductData.map(item => 
  item.filter((val,index) => {
    if(selection.includes(index)) {
      return index > 3; // this will return only the itemXAvailability
    }
  })
);
console.log(filtered);
```

The above snippet could be re-written this way.

```js
let selection = [0,1,3,4];
let allProductData = [['Item1Sku','Item1Name', 'Item1Desc', 'Item1Price', 'Item1Available', 'Item1Margin'], ['Item2Sku','Item2Name', 'Item2Desc', 'Item2Price', 'Item2Available', 'Item2Margin'], ['Item3Sku','Item3Name', 'Item3Desc', 'Item3Price', 'Item3Available', 'Item3Margin']];
let filtered = allProductData.map(item => 
  item.filter((val,index) => selection.includes(index) && index > 3)
);
console.log(filtered);
```

Two more examples using `Boolean` **true**, **false** as values of the array to test.

```js
let selection = [0,1,3,4];
let allProductData = [[true,true, false, true, false, true], [true,true,true,true,true,true], [false,false,false,false,false,false]];
let filtered = allProductData.map(item => 
  item.filter((val,index) => selection.includes(index) && index > 3)
);
console.log(filtered);
filtered.forEach((item) => item.forEach((val) => console.log(typeof(val))));
```

Notice the difference in the output.

```js
let selection = [0,1,3,4];
let allProductData = [[true,true, false, true, false, true], [true,true,true,true,true,true], [false,false,false,false,false,false]];
let filtered = allProductData.map(item => 
  item.filter((val,index) => {
    if(selection.includes(index) && index > 3) {
      return val;
    }
    })
);
console.log(filtered);
filtered.forEach((item) => item.forEach((val) => console.log(typeof(val))));
```

Two more examples using numbers. Output differs for value being `0`.

```js
let selection = [0,1,3,4];
let allProductData = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [6,5,4,3,2,1], [8,8,8,8,0,8]];
let filtered = allProductData.map(item => 
  item.filter((val,index) => selection.includes(index) && index > 3)
);
console.log(filtered);
filtered.forEach((item) => item.forEach((val) => console.log(typeof(val))));
```

```js
let selection = [0,1,3,4];
let allProductData = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [6,5,4,3,2,1], [8,8,8,8,0,8]];
let filtered = allProductData.map(item => 
  item.filter((val,index) => {
    if(selection.includes(index) && index > 3) {
      return val;
    }
    })
);
console.log(filtered);
filtered.forEach((item) => item.forEach((val) => console.log(typeof(val))));
```

What would be the difference when using `null` as our value.

```js
let selection = [0,1,3,4];
let allProductData = [[null,null,null,null,null,null], [null,null,null,null,null,null], [null,null,null,null,null,null]];
let filtered = allProductData.map(item => 
  item.filter((val,index) => selection.includes(index) && index > 3)
);
console.log(filtered);
filtered.forEach((item) => item.forEach((val) => console.log(typeof(val))));
```

```js
let selection = [0,1,3,4];
let allProductData = [[null,null,null,null,null,null], [null,null,null,null,null,null], [null,null,null,null,null,null]];
let filtered = allProductData.map(item => 
  item.filter((val,index) => {
    if(selection.includes(index) && index > 3) {
      return val;
    }
    })
);
console.log(filtered);
filtered.forEach((item) => item.forEach((val) => console.log(typeof(val))));
```

Comment: filter() expects a boolean returned, not the element value. This is only working in this case because all the strings are truthy. Would break if any of the values were `0` or null or NaN etc. Just return the `includes()` statement

Comment: @charlietfl yes i see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter and i edited my answer. It worked before also but to be exact that is the syntax.

Comment: @charlietfl the actual word is **not needed**. The condition if true it returns the val. So you are correct and this is why i edited accordingly, it is not needed to return the val;

Comment: Returning the element value in `filter()` is not correct as it assumes all values are truthy/falsy. You are misunderstanding the whole point. No need to be rude!! All my comments were constructive not insulting

Comment: @charlietfl if there was an error wouldn't then an error appear? Would it return the same result if it could not work that way also?  Please check the edit and be sure that i am true when saying that i am not rude. On all the examples that you will see in my edit the thing that you have to understand is that in all callback functions the outcome is the one that matches the conditions met in the callback, so actually the callback returns a value that coerces to true. I would like to see the people or person that up-voted your comments to up-vote this one also after running the examples.

Comment: There was no error in this case because strings with length are ***truthy*** but are not exactly equivalent to `true` or `false` booleans as expected per the documentation you linked to. If the array was `[555, 666, 0, 0, 0]` the condition would not work for example because returning the element`0` would be falsy

Comment: @charlietfl there is an edit please check. The output is not the same when dealing with `null` or `false`. But no error is raised. So yes you are b***ng since the question involved `strings`. Not to mention that my main answer in this is the first snippet which is the most efficient. So next time that you would like to be strict to me sir do think that i can be also, so the **most proper** comment to use was that the most efficient way is way A not B. PS, thanks for the comments since it lead to a very nice answer.

Comment: You are over reacting... within filter some condition should be used to return a boolean...that's all. It is how it is documented and how to avoid unwanted side effects

Comment: @charlietfl as said i am not over-reacting. I have presented several cases that pin-point that you are the one that is over-reacting. The only cases that those two ways provide different output is for `null` or `0` or `false`, so as a developer it would be easy for you or anyone else to handle that. But to be strict to the manual you would see that the recommended and most efficient way to write this snippet is the first one on top of the answer. And all of those cases where created to provide examples for even the cases that you have mentioned. I am never rude with not-rude people.

Comment: There are more falsy values than that ...empty string, NaN, undefined etc. I just don't understand why following docs and always return a boolean is so difficult. Avoiding unwanted side effects is important and if you were to do this in TypeScript would also have issues with your approach

Comment: @charlietfl i really don't understand is your head in the proper place mate? The answer is the first snippet. All the others are meant to display several cases that one should take notice before writing. On some occasions you might want to put all the ones you mentioned such as `null`,`0`,`empty string`,`false`,`Nan`,`undefined` in one bucket calling it `empty`.

Comment: @charlietfl On most occasions where you would want to be strict to type you would follow the recommended answer on top which also return the proper data-type as shown in the snippet. What on earth are you not getting? Who is actually the over-reacting person me? There are 10 or more comments on this issue only because you fail to understand that the correct and recommended snippet is the first one. The rest indicate a certain behavior. If you could handle it then perhaps you could use it if it suited your purposes.

Comment: @charlietfl More than that an answer here is not to use as is, but for the person that asks to get an idea on how to proceed with his/her problem.

Comment: I'm simply responding to your over reaction to a very simple and truthful and constructive comment that for some reason has gotten under your skin for whatever reason. As for who answers are for .... they are indeed intended for future readers and not just the person asking. This site is a knowledge base not just a help desk. As such, best practices should be considered, not ignored

Comment: @charlietfl i think i provide an answer that shows a lot. Under my skin is nothing but muscles and bones and blood i don't keep anything else there :) Besides i do have an application of my own where some unwanted values had to go to a `bucket` called `empty` and had all the values mentioned in the above comment. On that occasion i would use the second way because it is more efficient (returned the same output for all those cases check the numbers and boolean examples above). If you can't understand this then that is no problem. So bottom-line this is a great answer (if you can see it).

Answer (score 0):

Use array.map and array.filter for it.

```js
var selection = [0,1,3,4];
var allProductData = [['Item1Sku','Item1Name', 'Item1Desc', 'Item1Price', 'Item1Available', 'Item1Margin'], ['Item2Sku','Item2Name', 'Item2Desc', 'Item2Price', 'Item2Available', 'Item2Margin'], ['Item3Sku','Item3Name', 'Item3Desc', 'Item3Price', 'Item3Available', 'Item3Margin']];

let result = allProductData.map(data => {
    return data.filter((el, ind) => selection.indexOf(ind)!=-1);
})

console.log(result);
```